# Dynamics 365 Odata Feed Filter Condition on nested property result error

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to retrieve data from odata filter condition based on ownerid/Name.

Here is the example of my json format data which I received from odata without any filter condition:

```
{
activityid: "20a82acf-093e-e711-8101-5065f38b85e1",
regardingobjectid: null,
prioritycode: {
Name: "Normal",
Value: 1
},
scheduledstart: "2017-05-21T10:00:00Z",
scheduledend: "2017-05-21T10:00:00Z",
location: null,
statecode: {
Name: "Completed",
Value: 1
},
ownerid: {
Id: "064f5f55-e930-e711-80fe-5065f38aba91",
Name: "Diana Lee"
},
list-id: "f9a57b07-ee3f-e711-8100-5065f38b0571",
view-id: "bc829d10-a49d-409d-9a61-918fedadbad9",
entity-permissions-enabled: null
},
```

When i called the following url with filter condition data is retrieving:

```
~/_odata/Appointments?$filter=statecode/Value eq 1
```

but when I called the url with following filter condition data is not retrieve:

```
~/_odata/Appointments?$filter=ownerid/Name eq 'Diana Lee'
```

Please help me to retrieve the data based on owner name.

Answer (score 0):

One way that works is to expand the Owner relationship, and filter on the expanded relationship:

```
~/OrganizationData.svc/AppointmentSet?$expand=user_appointment&$filter=user_appointment/FullName eq 'Diana Lee'
```

And you can add a select clause to narrow the projection:

```
~/OrganizationData.svc/AppointmentSet?$select=Subject,OwnerId,user_appointment/FullName&$expand=user_appointment&$filter=user_appointment/FullName eq 'Diana Lee'
```